# Jitpack failing a build with Misconfigured Toolchain

Tags: java, maven, jitpack

I am trying to compile a forked repo with [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) becaause the repo is not published to maven and has several bugfixes over its prior release that is published on maven. However, I keep getting a misconfigured toolchain error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain (default) on project microbean-kubernetes-controller: Misconfigured toolchains. Non-existing JDK home configuration at /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle -> [Help 1]
```

I've been at this for a few hours now, and I have basically given up.

The repo is at: https://github.com/asuprem/microbean-kubernetes-controller

The pom.xml is at: https://github.com/asuprem/microbean-kubernetes-controller/blob/master/pom.xml

The build log for jitpack is at: https://jitpack.io/com/github/asuprem/microbean-kubernetes-controller/v0.2.3.3/build.log

I am specifically getting the following error:

```
[INFO] Required toolchain: jdk [ version='1.8' ]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.134 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-20T20:06:17Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain (default) on project microbean-kubernetes-controller: Misconfigured toolchains. Non-existing JDK home configuration at /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle -> [Help 1]
```

I thought this was because the original repo did not specify a `maven-compiler-plugin` so I added the following to the pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It *does* compile locally though.

I also tried adding a `jitpack.yml` with:

```
jdk:
  - openjdk8
```

because I thought the error was the `usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle` bit, but that also failed, so I removed it.

I know I am missing something probably incredibly simple, but staring at the logs isn't helping anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?  Running into it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error. It turns out my `toolchains.xml` file, which maven was reading when trying to locate the appropriate JDK for the toolchain, was invalid - it had an entry for `<jdkHome>` that pointed to a location that did not exist.

The solution was to simply correct the incorrect path in my `toolchains.xml` file and then everything worked just fine.